# Clarification of axis used for min/max scaling for data I have

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am building a neural network with keras and need clarification for the pre-processing step.

I have a dataframe that is 1-n **rows (features** for the machine learning algorithm to learn from) and 1-n columns each column being a **sample**

My data is currently correctly log-transformed and i simply need to squish to between 0 and 1. I am using the `minmax_scale` in sklearn and the processing of my data is as follows:

```
##transpose counts::rows samples and cols features (to correct format for NN)
counts = normCounts.transpose()

##scale counts
scaled = preprocessing.minmax_scale(counts, feature_range=(0,1))
```

I need clarification on which way around the dataframe needs to be. Reading the minmax documentation on sklearn says that the data are scaled along `axis=0`

does this mean:

```
       featurecolumn1, featurecolumn2...
sample1 ->
sample2 ->
```

??

Basically, what I need to ensure is that low counts on the original dataframe are closer to the 0 and the upper end on the dataframe are closer to one... however, I am unsure now as to whether this should actually be the other way around... so not transposing the dataframe from the beginning:

```
         sample1, sample2...
feature1 ->
feature2 ->
```

Would really appreciate clarification here!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, whenever we talk about we usually want to scale the features. So if your data is in format like

```
          feature 1  feature 2
sample 1 
sample 2
```

Then you should apply

```
minmax_scale(data) # By default axis is 0
```

And if your data is in format like

```
          sample 1  sample 2
feature 1 
feature 2
```

Then you should apply

```
minmax_scale(data, axis =1 )
```

I guess with axis = 0 it takes the columns of any dataframe and with axis=1 it takes the rows of the dataframe. Whatever they have written in their documentation but it behaves like that only

**EDIT**

Reply to your comment -

You can do standard scaling where the data values will be mean centered with a unit deviation

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
 
 scale = StandardScaler().fit(data)
 scale.transform(data)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! so I have a follow up questions to thi which is the reason I asked - and I am unsure about how to correct this: I thought it was the first format which to me makes sense, however I need to subset my data to contain some samples that the neural network is never trained on (not a test either)..

now when I scale in the same manner (format one, scaling features)  there are features that have really low counts, but are now all majority 0.9 / 1 because the range of values in all those samples is between 3 and 3.5 i am unsure therefore as to why this is happening and how to correct.

Comment: Hey, I have edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: thank you so much! I have also found that scaling at axis=1 (so scaling across samples) preserves the level of counts really well, so low counts are low on the scale and high counts are high on the scale - Although my features are independent, they are all created on a common scale, so min_max at axis=1 also makes perfect sense for my data! Accepting your answer also :) thank you!